# Appending separate divs from selected items

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display the text of only the selected items when the submit button is clicked. The issue I'm getting is all selected items get put into a single `<div>` element. Is there a way to make each selected item go into their own `<div>` element?

Here is the html for the button items that can be selected:

```
<div class="select-group">
    <p class="item-selection">item 1</p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default check">Add Item</button>
    <p class="item-selection">item 2</p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default check">Add Item</button>
    <p class="item-selection">item 3</p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default check">Add Item</button>
</div>

<a class="submit-ct" href="#">
  Submit Order
</a>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$('.submit-ct').on('click', function(){
  if ( $( '.btn' ).hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
    var itemSelected = $( '.btn.active' ).prev().text();
    $("<div>"+itemSelected+"</div>").attr('class', 'item-list-select').appendTo(".item-list");
  } 
})
```

Comment: Loop trough it, get the selected item length.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```js
$('.select-group').on('click', '.btn', function() {
  var btn = $(this);
  if (btn.hasClass('active')) {
    btn.removeClass('active');
  } else {
    btn.addClass('active');
  }
});

$('.submit-ct').on('click', function(){
  var itemSelected = $( '.btn.active' ).prev().text();
  if (!itemSelected) return;
  $("<div>"+itemSelected+"</div>").attr('class', 'item-list-select').appendTo(".item-list");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-group">
    <p class="item-selection">item 1</p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default check">Add Item</button>
    <p class="item-selection">item 2</p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default check">Add Item</button>
    <p class="item-selection">item 3</p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default check">Add Item</button>
</div>

<h3>selected:</h3>
<div class="item-list"></div>

<a class="submit-ct" href="#">
  Submit Order
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by using `each()`

```
$('.submit-ct').on('click', function(){
    $( '.btn.active' ).each(function() {
      var itemSelected = $( this ).prev().text();
      $("<div>"+itemSelected+"</div>").attr('class', 'item-list-select').appendTo(".item-list");
    });
})
```